# Android transition between listviews

Tags: android, android-animation

How can I add a transition (right to left) to listviews? I need to create a category/sub-category selection and all of the samples I have found, are using a new activity for each ListView.

Comment: Have you looked at ViewFlipper? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have each of the listViews in their own fragments, or even have both listViews in the same activity.  If both in their own fragment, have a container Activity that contains both of them.

Have the category list original fill the width of their shared view container, and have the subcategory list be aligned to the right of the category view (presumably off screen)

When you want two switch from category to subcategory, use a ScaleAnimation to shrink the category listView from full width to 0.  As it shrinks, the other view will "slide" in from the right.

You can customize and control this with whatever effect you want to have.